# Any way to get old Intel graphics support on 17.10?

Tags: drivers, video, intel-graphics, vlc, 17.10

Previously been running 16.04 on my old Intel 945GM powered laptop.  Been able to watch 720p, and 1080p, movies smoothly play through VLC.

Tried 17.10 (fully installed on an SSD) and while it's great, I notice that there doesn't seem to be any acceleration anymore and even SD video is choppy.  In the Settings program, until Details, Graphics is listed as 'Unknown'.

Is there anyway to get backwards compatibility between the two?   Would prefer not to have to go back to 16.04

Comment: "unknown" may be because of not having `mesa-utils` installed.  Don't think it will help with the rest though.

Comment: Make sure you have enabled intel-microcode in additional drivers as well. If you're missing it, your CPU may have reverted to older and buggy behavior. Also, are you using Wayland or Xorg on 17.10? Try choosing the Xorg session at login screen if you're on Wayland. It might perform better there.

Comment: @dobey - Logging in with X.Org solved the VLC problem - playback is smooth, and the Graphics  entry on Details shows "945GM".  

The flip side is that Chrome fullscreen video playback is now stuttery.  From my time on 16.04 I learnt to select "Override software rendering list" to enable smooth scrolling in fullscreen mode. 

In Wayland Chrome video playback is smooth even in HD.  

It would be great if they can get the 945GM drivers working with Wayland but will use X.org in the meantime.  Hope that this remains as an option in 18.04 LTS